# UTC date parsing inconsistency in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

Something weird is happening while parsing a `UTC/GMT` date. I set the date format as

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

where `Z` is for `UTC`. And I give following date string to parse:

```
String startTimestampString = "2013-10-02T00:00:00Z";
```

I hope to get same date as output but instead it shows

```
2013-10-01 17:00:00.0
```

Now sure from where this 7 hour lag coming from?

**Code:**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
       SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
       date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
       System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").toString());

       String startTimestampString = "2013-10-02T00:00:00Z";
       long startTimestamp = date.parse(startTimestampString).getTime();
       System.out.println(String.format("Long %d and timestamp %s", startTimestamp, new Timestamp(startTimestamp).toString()));        
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
Long 1380672000000 and timestamp 2013-10-01 17:00:00.0    // ERROR timestamp should have been 2013-10-02 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: In your format, Z is a literal.

Comment: You understand that `TimeStamp` has no concept of `Timezone`, so it converts the UTC date in your local timezone while printing.

Comment: Actually I did not know that! So it is printing in PST. Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## java.util.Date Has No Time Zone

As the comments said, your problem is not understanding the confusing way in which java.util.Date works.

> A `Date` object has no time zone, but *seems* to have one because its `toString` method applies your JVM's default time zone when generating the textual representation (the String being returned).

This poor design choice by the Java team has caused so much confusion, including countless similar Questions on StackOverflow.

## The Date Is Not The String

A key idea here is that the String generated by the `toString` method is an entirely new object. This string is *not* the Date. The string is a particular representation of that moment in history as seen from you default time zone. The same moment in history appears as two different time-of-day values when seen from the Paris or Montréal or Kolkata time zones.

## Avoid java.util.Date

Do not waste your time with java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat. They are notoriously troublesome. Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) (inspired by Joda-Time).

## Joda-Time

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3. Your format is in the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 as its defaults, so no need for parsers/formatters in your case. Joda–Time automatically uses built-in formatters to parse ISO 8601 compliant strings.

```
String input = "2013-10-02T00:00:00Z";
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeParis = new DateTime( input, timeZoneParis );
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTimeParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime dateTimeIndia = dateTimeParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeParis.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal: " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal formatted: " + formatter.print( dateTimeMontréal ) );
System.out.println( "dateTimeIndia: " + dateTimeIndia );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeParis: 2013-10-02T02:00:00.000+02:00
dateTimeMontréal: 2013-10-01T20:00:00.000-04:00
dateTimeMontréal formatted: mardi 1 octobre 2013 20 h 00 EDT
dateTimeIndia: 2013-10-02T05:30:00.000+05:30
dateTimeUtc: 2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z
```