# SimpleDateFormat.parse() not using the correct date format

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

So I'm trying to parse a string with a date into another format but it's not changing the format. The parse function seems to overriding the SimpleDateFormat settings perhaps?

```
Date dateOfItem = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(item.date);
Log.v("APP", dateOfItem.toString());
```

item.date for example is this: **Tue, 12 May 2015**
And thats exactly how I want the format to be in the Date. But the Log shows it as: **Tue May 12 00:00:00 CDT 2015** which is not the format that I have in the SimpleDateFormat.

So how can take that string and convert it to a date with the format that I have as the parameter in the SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22259712/642706) and my answer for more details and for an alternative using the Joda-Time library. Also,see the [`DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "F-" )`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forStyle(java.lang.String)) command on Joda-Time for such formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) does not have a format. It simply

> represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision

What you see in your logs is the result of `Date#toString()`.

So either use a `SimpleDateFormat` to [`format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) your `Date` object or use the original `String` value you had.

Answer (score 1):

use this process

```
             DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss E", Locale.getDefault());
              curdate =  df.parse("String date");  
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy");
           newFormat = formatter.format(curdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the reverse parsing.

You have the item.data which is in the `E, d MMMM yyyy` format and then parse it. 
If you want to print the date in a specified format, you should use SimpleDateFormat#format method.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM yyyy");
Log.v("APP", sdf.format(item.date));
```

Also check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date))

Answer (score 1):

You're starting with a `String` and putting in a `Date`. And that is all you are using the `SimpleDateFormat` for.

Then you are using the date's default `toString()` method, so it's not going to apply any custom formatting.

What you need to do is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dateOfItem = format.parse(item.date); //string to date
Log.v("APP", format.format(dateOfItem)); //or date to string
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Log.v("APP", formatter.format(dateOfItem));
```

Using `dateOfItem.toString()` uses its own [output format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).